# UITextField text not appearing when set by delegate method

Tags: ios, swift

I'm implementing a barcode scanner for my app using the google books api. The data gets fetched successfully and stored in the proper textfields:

```
func readInJSON(controller: UIViewController, title: String, author: String, imageLink: String) {
    self.titleTextField.text = title
    self.authorTextField.text = author
}
```

However the text does not actually appear in the textFields until I tap on the them, then the text populates. I'm wondering if there is some way to have the text appear without having a user tap on the text fields themselves.

Comment: where are you calling this method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are not on the main thread. UI operation should be done on the main thread.
Try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.titleTextField.text = title
    self.authorTextField.text = author
}
```